# sscanf: Get a pointer to end position

Tags: c, pointers, scanf

I want to parse a `const char *str` string, and I need to read it by parts, with several calls to `sscanf()`

I have some example of what I could do if it was text of a file, which could be parsed with `fscanf()`, which updates the `FILE *fp` pointer to the position it stops reading:

```
fscanf(fp, "name    %s ", name);
fscanf(fp, "date    %*i ");
fscanf(fp, "{ ");
fscanf(fp, "    isdst   %*i ");
fscanf(fp, "    yday    %*i ");
fscanf(fp, "    wday    %*i ");
fscanf(fp, "    year    %i ", &year);
fscanf(fp, "    mon %i ", &mon);
fscanf(fp, "    mday    %i ", &day);
```

But `sscanf()` doesn't update the pointer.  Is there a way to do this?

**EDIT:**

From @pmg comment, I have this code now:

```
if (sscanf(str, " %lf%n", &a, &pos) != 1)
    goto err;
str += pos;
if (sscanf(str, " %i%n", &b, &pos) != 1)
    goto err;
str += pos;
```

which should be equivalent to a one line:

```
if (sscanf(str, " %lf %i", &a, &b) != 2)
    goto err;
```

Is this what %n does?

Comment: use `"%n"` conversion specifier in format string ... and corresponding variable

Comment: I suggest you read *lines*, and then use `sscanf` to parse the lines you want to parse (skipping the lines you don't want to parse). And always check what any `scanf`-like function *returns*. My guess is that the parsing you do doesn't work, and `fscanf` will at some point return `0` (or even `EOF`?).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, I should check fscanf, but it was reading a file that I wrote and know that does contain all that, so it never fails at that point (although it might be better to check anyway, because someone could modify it maliciously, so thanks)

Comment: @pmg Yeah, I think that is the exact answer I was looking for!

Comment: Glad I could help. Have fun :)

Comment: Please, post it as an answer, so that I can vote it as an answer! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `"%n"` conversion specifier in format string ... and corresponding variable.